# Generator expressions inside of target_link_libraries

Tags: cmake

I have this particular call to `target_link_libraries` that I am trying to get working.

```
target_link_libraries(
  Array
  $<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:Clang>: c++abi>
  $<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:GNU>: c++ c++abi c gcc_s gcc>
)
```

It is outputting a build command like this:

```
clang++ CMakeFiles/Array.dir/driver.cpp.o CMakeFiles/Array.dir/Array.cpp.o  -o Array $<1: -lc++abi> $<0: -lc++ -lc++abi -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc>
```

Am I writing the generator expressions correctly or is the call to `target_link_libraries` wrong?

Comment: Just guessing: can you remove the space after `:` and try? Also split the `c++ c++abi c gcc_s gcc` on separate `$<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:GNU>:c++>` `$<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:GNU>:c++abi>` and so on.

Comment: @KamilCuk doesn't fix it, just removes the space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I fixed it my putting the the generators in quotes and replacing spaces with semi-colons.

```
target_link_libraries(
  Array
  "$<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:Clang>:c++abi>"
  "$<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:GNU>:c++;c++abi;c;gcc_s;gcc>"
)
```